# Resize images to very small n x n dimensions

Tags: python, image, resize, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I am resizing my images to 50 x 50 in python. Skimage transform and PIL thumbnail both resize the image while preserving the aspect ratio. 
Whats the other way to do it?
I have tried:
For PIL thumbnail,

```
im.thumbnail((50,50),Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

This gives me a (42,50) image not a (50,50) image.

For skimage.transform

```
image = skimage.transform.resize(image, (50, 50))
```

It returns a completely distorted image.

Comment: what's the size of your original?

Comment: If you don't want distorted proportions, then scale based on shortest side and crop after

Comment: Original size of images varies from (400, 800) to (20,30). I have tried scaling and cropping but that also ends up in a distorted or completely black image.

Comment: What is the desired behavior if the original is not square? Should it stretch, add white or black bars along the edges, or crop?

Comment: crop if the image is not square.
I tried another method of first resizing while preserving range and later central crop. But result is still distorted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `im.resize((50,50), Image.ANTIALIAS)`

Answer (score 0):

To resize to fixed size while maintaining aspect ratio and cropping to fit, use [`PIL.ImageOps.fit(image,size)`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html?highlight=crop#PIL.ImageOps.fit)

```
import PIL.ImageOps
import PIL.Image
impath = '1-True Mountain Covered with Cloud.jpg'
im = PIL.Image.open(impath)
display(im)
```

[image: original]

```
imfit = PIL.ImageOps.fit(im, (64,64))
display(imfit)
```

[image: fit]